# How to navigate to Home Directory?

Tags: command-line, bash

My terminal used to read

```
username@computername:~$
```

but after navigating to some directories, it now says

```
username@computername:/$
```

and I can't get back to my Home directory.

Comment: Check this [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal)

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way is to simply type `cd`. Argumentless `cd` means `cd` will bring you to your home directory, which is also known as `~`. This means `cd ~` would also work, albeit with a couple more keystrokes.

Comment: For more info on cd and cd ~/ :
[ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84615/difference-between-cd-and-cd ]